# problem in installation of ubuntu linux from cd

Tags: software-installation

I want to install Linux Ubuntu on my computer. But since I want to install it by cd.

How much disk partition is needed for installation of Ubuntu Linux from cd...

Comment: That will vary but I'd not recommend anything less than 40 GB total if you're going to be using the OS for anything of value. There are also more than one partition variations to consider. We really don't have enough information to give you a complete and valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if you are asking how much disk space is needed for install ubuntu or how many partitions you should make.
I suggest you to read some installation guides and clarify your question.

Comment: I am asking how many partitions should I make

Comment: It depends. For a normal user I think that install all the system in 1 partition is OK. But if you want to have your /home directory in a separated partition (maybe to recover your data in case of system error) or even other directories like /var, you should have as many paritition as you need. I think is preferable to have your /home directory in other partition so my recommendation is to have 2 partitions

Answer (score 0):

Atleast two partition is needed to install Ubuntu or any Linux on your system. One partition is for the root directory and the other one is for swap. The partion for the bootloader will be created automatically. We need atleast 4 GB for installing the root partition.